# Create a service for lc_adapter.exe in Windows - Error 1053

Tags: windows, service

I have a program named lc_adapter.exe.
The program is used to foward syslogs from a firewall to [LimaCharlie.io](https://limacharlie.io/).

I want the program to start as a service.

I have tried the following two different commands.

**Command 1**

```
lc_adapter.exe -install:LCAdapterInstalled syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=a-b-c-d-e client_options.identity.oid=1-2-3-4-5 client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=fw-paloalto-data client_options.sensor_seed_key=fw-paloalto-data port=2026 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=true
```

This gives:

starting
Service LCAdapterInstalled installed.

But it does not appear as a service in Windows Services.

**Command 2**

```
sc.exe create LCAdapterService binPath= "C:\LCAdapter\lc_adapter.exe syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=a-b-c-f-e client_options.identity.oid=1-2-3-4-5 client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=htv-fw-data client_options.sensor_seed_key=htv-fw-data port=2099 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=true"
```

The service appeared in Services, but it will not start as it gives me error 1053.

[image]

[image]

What can I do to debug?

Comment: Stick with the documentation (option 1). Using sc isn't going to work.